# How can you conditionally include protocols during compiliation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to conditionally include a protocol?  For example, below is some code that does not work, but should give you an idea what I'm referring to.  I only want the interface AdWhirlDelegate to be included if ads are turned on.

```
// this works fine
#if ADS_SUPPORTED
#import "AdWhirlView.h"
#endif

// this does NOT work
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate #if ADS_SUPPORTED ,AdWhirlDelegate #endif>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
#if ADS_SUPPORTED
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,AdWhirlDelegate>
#else
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
#endif
```

...but then IB can get a little confused. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177040/how-to-use-different-interface-declarations-at-compile-time-without-confusing-int), which presents an alternative to that.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work

Repeat the interface declaration twice , one with the protocol and one without blocked inside the #if/#else/#endif structure

Preprocessor directives will only work in a non nested way like your header include.