# How can I conditionally declare a delegate in an interface declaration?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, delegates

I have an Xcode 4 project that builds to two different targets. I've defined some constants in the build settings so I can run different code for each target like this:

```
#ifdef VERSION1
// do this
#else
// do that
#endif
```

In one version of the app, I need the main view controller to open another view controller and become its delegate, but the other version doesn't use that view controller and shouldn't compile its code or try to become its delegate. I've set up the main view controller header like this:

```
#ifdef VERSION2
#import "SpecialViewController.h"
#endif

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, SpecialViewControllerDelegate> {
// etc.
```

The conditional around the #import tag works fine, but how can I declare this class to be the SpecialViewControllerDelegate in one version but not the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you conditionally include protocols during compiliation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514136/how-can-you-conditionally-include-protocols-during-compiliation)

Comment: Wow, I searched for pretty much those exact terms but didn't see that. That question links to this one which also has a nice solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177040/how-to-use-different-interface-declarations-at-compile-time-without-confusing-int

Comment: I only found it because I remembered reading it the other day. The SO search is (intentionally) inferior to Google in many cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use a #define preprocessor directive to change the delegates between versions.
Here's an example for "VERSION2".

```
#ifdef VERSION2
#import "SpecialViewController.h"
#define ARGS PMediaPickerControllerDelegate, SpecialViewControllerDelegate 
#endif

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <ARGS>
```

Comment: Interesting, how do you deal with methods that are required to implement as the delegate? #ifdef around those as well?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the grammar of your question.
Methods implemented as the delegate?

Maybe you could paste a method example and that would help me determine that way to answer this.

Comment: Some protocols require you to implement certain methods, e.g. `UITableViewDataSource` requires you to implement `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

Comment: I see.
Yes, I would use #ifdefs here.

Should the need arise for many different versions, rather than 2, I would separate this into files based on version and change the makefile to use the appropriate file based on version number.

Comment: Interesting point. I do have a method that refers to the SpecialViewController (the method that opens it) and that gave errors in version 1, but I used the ifdefs to hide that method in version 1. In other cases I think it wouldn't hurt to leave the methods there and they would just be unused. Anyway, this solution is working for me -- I can build both versions now -- and I'm glad I didn't have to create any redundant code.

Comment: Good for you! Gotta' love simple code fixes to stay away from redundant code.
Do you mind up voting the answer?

Comment: u saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't assign the delegate you should be fine leaving the implementation. Your SpecialViewController in VERSION1 (if you even have a SpecialViewController in V1) will not have a delegate so its calls will go nowhere, which should lead to no side effects.

```
#ifdef VERSION2
specialViewController.delegate = self;
#endif
```

If this approach doesn't work it almost seems like you should have a different MainViewController for each target.

Comment: I don't want to import the SpecialViewController header in version 1 because that leads to a bunch of other code that doesn't need to be compiled into that version of the app. I'll update my question to mention that. (If I don't include the header but leave the interface declaration, the compiler stops with the error "Cannot find protocol declaration for SpecialViewControllerDelegate.")